# using mgfs to find limiting distribution

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution, moment-generating-function

Can someone help me out with proving that the limiting distribution of a negative binomial (k,p) distributed variable is poisson if we let k -> infinity and p->1. I am just learning about limiting distributions so if someone could break down the steps nicely it would be great.

Comment: As the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) explains: $\quad$ **•** *Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. [...]* $\quad$ **•** *Ask about specific problems you have encountered in your initial efforts. If you can't do that yet, try some more of your own work first or searching for more general help.* $\qquad$ You should also read the guidelines for answering such questions there -- you shouldn't get the kind of answer you ask for. See also the paragraph on homework in the [help](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I'd suggest you start by writing down the MGF for the negative binomial and the Poisson.